# Flutter iOS module can't access new Swift file and print not working

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am working in a `Flutter` app and need to call native `iOS` code from it. I added a new `Swift` file to the `iOS` module in the app but it can't access it from `AppDelegate`. I also tried to print some log statements, but print is not working.

Every time I try to access the new file from `AppDelegate`, it gives me this error:

```
use of unresolved identifier 'NewFile'
```

The AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method looks like this:

```
let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
let testChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.test.example/example",
                                          binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
testChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
  [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
    guard call.method == "testExample" else {
      print("can't call testExample method")
      result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
      return
    }
    print("can call testExample method")
    NewFile() //This is the new file I am trying to access
    result(10) //10 is just for testing
})
```

Why it doesn't access the `NewFile.swift` created in the same directory as the `AppDelegate`? Also why the `print` statement doesn't log anything to the console?

I am using Visual Studio Code.

Should I add configuration or linking to allow Visual studio code to access me file and also log my print statements?

Comment: it would be best to show some of your code!

Comment: @Fattie I have added some code and more details

Comment: ok, what is "NewFile()"  ?  pls paste in the code for that, and, explain how you are including it (or whatever the process is).  it could be something simple, such as you forgot to mark it public, or ??

Comment: It is a simple class, just to implement some functionality that will be called automatically from a third party. This third party requires a separate class with specific name. This name is not NewFile of course, but I just set it as an example here

Comment: it's very likely you have made a mistake along the lines of "you forgot the public", or, it is not actually being included in the right way (for example, something like " you need using Blah in the consumer class". Good luck!

Comment: @Fattie Sorry but I am new to Flutter, what is blah ?

Comment: I just meant "for example"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding new files to the iOS module should be done from Xcode not from Visual Studio Code. When I added new files from Xcode it could access it easily.

It also seems that log statements in iOS works only on Xcode.